# Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Uniform$(0,2)$ random variables find $P(XY<1)$

Tags: probability

So far I got this
First
$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}$$
Then i find $P(XY≥1)$
$$\int_1^2\int_{1/y}^2f_{XY}(x,y)\text{d}x\text{d}y=\frac{2}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\ln(2)$$
Then i find the complement
$$P(XY<1)=1-P(XY≥1)=\frac{2}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\ln(2)$$
Is this the right way of doing it?
I also tried using the law of total probability but ended up with a different answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct but your limits of integration are not.

Please skech the graph of $y=1/x$ and check your limits again.

My concern is about your $1$ in the lower bound.

Comment: Well, it would make the most sense to me if it was 0 but then I would have to do ln(0) which is undefined. This is also why i wasn't sure if it was right but all the other methods I tried involved ln(0) and i got stuck because of that.

Comment: It is not zero, think about $1/2$

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry, I just looked at the graph and understand now. Both my variables are uniform(0,2) so i have to keep them in this interval and the function y=1/x  exceeds this at 1/2. thank you very much!